# How do I express that I want to do something "if a function returns true/false"

Tags: c++, syntax, boolean

I am making a dictionary program. Before adding a word to the dictionary, the AddWord function calls the SearchForWord function, if the search functions discovers that the word passed to it is already in the dictionary it returns true.

In the add function I want it to move on to the part where it actually adds the word only if the search function returns false (meaning it did not find the word) and I can't figure out how to express this correctly.

Edit: I copied and pasted this all from emacs and the formatting is funky, don't hate.

```
bool Dictionary:: AddAWord(string word)
{
  ofstream fout;  
  string fileName="#.txt";  
  fileName[0]=toupper(word[0]);  

  if(SearchForWord(word)=false){   //here i figured the SearchForWord function would be called and return either true or false  
    //add word  
  }else{  
    //dont add word  
  }
```

Here's the full search function if it helps

```
bool Dictionary::SearchForWord(string word)  
{  
   ofstream fout;  
   ifstream fin;  
   string x;  
   string fileName="#.txt";  
   fileName[0]=toupper(word[0]);  
   fout.open(fileName.data());  
   if(!fin.eof()){  
     while(fin>>x){  
      if(x=word){  
       cout<<"Word found during search";  
       return(Dictionary::success);  
      }  
     }  
    }else{  
       return(Dictionary::failure);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Is you dictionary really so big it has to live on disc rather than in memory? if not there maybe a data structure solution here. also SearchForWord appears to be wrong - it opens fout but searches in fin

Comment: Also, both functions make pointless copies of the strings, and if the word is not in the file, no value is returned.  Any compiler should warn about that though, be sure to turn on and look at the warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want;

```
if(SearchForWord(word) == false)
```

not

```
if(SearchForWord(word) = false)
```

As a point of style it would be better to go;

```
if( !SearchForWord(word) )
```

Or maybe even better;

```
bool word_found = SearchForWord(word);
if( !word_found )
```

I find it really useful to introduce well named boolean variables like that, it enhances readability because reading the conditional out loud in your head now results in "if not word found". Additionally it becomes easier and less confusing to trace progress within most debuggers.

Comment: I agree actually, I put up a quick answer and then started editing it, maybe not the best practice

Comment: (Sorry my comment no longer makes sense because the comment I was responding to has disappeared)

Comment: @Bill I tend to delete my comments that are no longer relevant.

Comment: Rather than introduce a named variable, why not give the function
a meaningful name: isPresent, or contains.  The name of a function will
usually be a verb or a verb phrase; a predicate function, which returns
a boolean, will often start with is, but other verbs which lead to an
unambiguous yes or no answer, like contains in this case, are also
acceptable.

Comment: @James - sure but often you don't get to choose the name of a function you're calling. One of the beauties of using a temporary bool for the job is that you can choose exactly the right name. It's effectively a comment.

Comment: @Bill Forster You mean like std::vector<>::empty() :-).  And I agree, using a significantly named variable is better than any contorted logic, and has some value even in simple cases when the function is misnamed.

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
if(!SearchForWord(word))
```

Never use `==` when comparing boolean values. You may accidentally assign the value like you are there. Consider this:

```
if(engagedInNuclearWar = true) { // typo. should be ==
    fireMissiles();
}
```

Now, when this fires, the first thing it will do, because there's only ONE equals sign, is assign `engagedInNuclearWar` to be true. This is a mistake, we want to be checking not assigning. As a result, we're firing missiles when we shouldn't. Some intern will probably lose his job over that (if he doesn't get killed in the nuclear holocaust that follows.)

Instead, avoid using == but rely on boolean evaluation.

```
if(engagedInNuclearWar) { // no chance for = vs == typo
    fireMissiles();
}
```

Comment: Another way to avoid accidental assignment is to put the literal value on the left, as in "if (true == engagedInNuclearWar)". If you typo that comparison, it turns into a compile-time error instead of a run-time bug.

Comment: @Sherm: Except now your code is much harder to read, because that's not how natural language expresses itself. Just turn up compiler warnings and/or learn from your mistakes, and you don't have to make damaging coding practices for a much longer time.

Comment: @sherm that's an option, of course. I personally feel it reads 'wrong.' It doesn't read like English. I consider recommending that for integer comparison, though. `if(numberOfNukesAvailable = 0)` is a bug, where `if(0 = numberOfNukesAvailable)` is an error.

Comment: @GMan - I *do* use -Wall, and I *have* learned from my mistakes. That's how I learned a safer way to write literal comparisons. Please don't make assumptions about people you don't know, OK?

Comment: @glowcoder - Yeah, it does read a bit awkward, and I wouldn't use it for cases (like bool) where I could avoid doing an explicit comparison to begin with. I'm just saying, "if (5 == foo)" is safer than "if (foo == 5)".

Comment: @Sherm: Haha, wow, you could reply to what I said but attacking me also works I guess. Well, congratulations on introducing a mental speed-bump for everyone else in your code, a permanent fix for a temporary problem.

Comment: @GMan - Attacking you? Are you serious? I made a polite request. I even said please!

Comment: @GMan - For the record, turning up compiler warnings isn't always effective, since some older compilers don't warn about it. My tactic guarantees a typo will produce an error in *any* compiler.

Comment: @Sherm: The use of older compilers is an exceptional case, which warrants no change on a general practice for modern times.

Comment: @GMan - Older compilers might be exceptional to *you*, but I deal with them every day. And even a current compiler isn't required by the language standard to emit such a warning.

Comment: @Sherm: It's exceptional not just to me, but to the general programming community, so you're working in an exceptional case. (New compilers are released more often than old compilers are maintained for a reason.) And no, warnings are not mentioned by the standard at all, but every modern compiler does anyway.

Comment: @Sherm: Oh, one of those "Experienced means I'm not wrong" types. Good job giving up to a simple reply, though, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!SearchForWord(word)) {
    // add the word
} else {
    // don't add the word
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to do:  if(!SearchForWord(word))

Using = is assignment not boolean.

Answer (score 0):

`=` is the assignment operator. It is used to assign a value to a variable(like `a=5`).To check if `a` is equal to `b` you have to write `a==b`.
So

```
if(SearchForWord(word)=false)
```

should be changed to

```
if(SearchForWord(word)==false)
```